# C typecasting from a signed char to int type

Tags: c, char, signed

In the below snippet, shouldn't the output be 1? Why am I getting output as -1 and 4294967295?
What I understand is, the variable, c, here is of signed type, so shouldn't its value be 1?

```
char c=0xff;
printf("%d %u",c,c);
```

Comment: The value of `c` is `0xFF` is `-1` if your `char` is `signed char`.

Comment: The second argument is passing a signed value to an unsigned format: the `-1` is unrepresentable, although *something* happens.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `char` and `signed char` are distinct types, even if type `char` happens to be signed.

Comment: @KeithThompson why is that so? *If* the compiler treats `char` as being signed, I thought that `char` is then shorthand for `signed char` in the same way that `int` is shorthand for `signed int` (and `unsigned` is shorthand for `unsigned int` though that's not quite the same thing). Or are `int` and `signed int` also distinct types?

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's so because the standard says so. `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types, two of which have the same range and representation. `int` and `signed int` (and `int signed`) are different names for the same type.  See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.2.5.

Comment: @KeithThompson thank you. My original first comment then should have been "if your `char` is signed."

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

c is of signed type. a char is 8 bits. So you have an 8 bit signed quantity, with all bits 1. On a twos complement machine, that evaluates to -1.

Some compilers will warn you when you do that sort of thing. If you're using gcc/clang, switch on all the warnings.

Pedant note: On some machines it could have the value 255, should the compiler treat 'char' as unsigned.

Comment: Btw, isn't it UB to pass `char` to `%u`?

Comment: I think it's UB to pass a signed value of any type to %u. But if char is unsigned, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the correct answer.

The `%u` format specifier indicates that the value will be an `unsigned int`. The compiler automatically promotes your 8-bit `char` to a 32-bit `int`. However you have to remember that `char` is a signed type. So a value of `0xff` is in fact -1.

When the casting from `char` to `int` occurs, the value is still -1, but the it's the 32-bit representation which in binary is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` or in hex `0xffffffff`

When that is interpreted as an unsigned integer, all of the bits are obviously preserved because the length is the same, but now it's handled as an unsigned quantity.

```
0xffffffff = 4294967295 (unsigned)
0xffffffff = -1 (signed)
```

Comment: It's implementation-defined whether the `char` is signed or not.

Comment: That's true, but for the implementation that the OP has, it's obviously signed.

Comment: During the casting, like above, are we getting all (32-8) bits as 1 just because the sign bit is 1?

Comment: The original 8-bit char contained -1, so the value held by the 32-bit int must also be -1. Otherwise the type-cast would also have changed the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are three character types in C, `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`.  Plain `char` has the same representation as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`; the choice is implementation-defined.  It appears that plain `char` is signed in your implementation.

All three types have the same size, which is *probably* 8 bits (`CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<limits.h>`, specifies the number of bits in a byte).  I'll assume 8 bits.

```
char c=0xff;
```

Assuming plain `char` is signed, the value `0xff` (`255`) is outside the range of type `char`. Since you can't store the value `255` in a `char` object, the value is implicitly converted. The result of this conversion is implementation-defined, but is very likely to be `-1`.

Keep this carefully in mind: `0xff` is simply another way to write `255`, and `0xff` and `-1` are two distinct values.  You *cannot* store the value `255` in a `char` object; its value is `-1`.  Integer constants, whether they're decimal, hexadecimal, or octal, specify values, not representations.

If you really want a one-byte object with the value `0xff`, define it as an `unsigned char`, not as a `char`.

```
printf("%d %u",c,c);
```

When a value of an integer type narrower than `int` is passed to `printf` (or to any variadic function), it's promoted to `int` if that type can hold the type's entire range of values, or to `unsigned int` if it can't. For type `char`, it's almost certainly promoted to `int`.  So this call is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d %u", -1, -1);
```

The output for the `"%d"` format is obvious.  The output for `"%u"` is less obvious.  `"%u"` tells `printf` that the corresponding argument is of type `unsigned int`, but you've passed it a value of type `int`. What *probably* happens is that the representation of the `int` value is treated *as if* it were of type `unsigned int`, most likely yielding `UINT_MAX`, which happens to be `4294967295` on your system.  If you really want to do that, you should *convert* the value to type `unsigned int`.  This:

```
printf("%d %u", -1, (unsigned int)-1);
```

is well defined.

Your two lines of code are playing a lot of games with various types, treating values of one type as if they were of another type, and doing implicit conversions that might yield results that are implementation-defined and/or depend on the choices your compiler happens to make.

Whatever you're trying to do, there's undoubtedly a cleaner way to do it (unless you're just trying to see what your implementation does with this particular code).

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with the assumption using OP's "c, here is of signed type"

```
char c=0xff;  // Implementation defined behavior.
```

`0xff` is a *hexadecimal constant* with the value of 255 and type of `int`.

> ...  the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.  §6.3.1.4 3

So right off, the value of `c` is implementation defined (ID).  Let us assume the common ID behavior of 8-bit wrap-around, so `c` --> -1.

---

A signed `char` will be promoted to `int` as part of a variadic argument to `printf("%d %u",c,c);` is the same as `printf("%d %u",-1, -1);`.  Printing the `-1` with `"%d"` is not an issue and `"-1"` is printed.

Printing an `int -1` with `"%x"` is undefined behavior (UB) as it is a mis-matched specifier/type and does not fall under the exception of being representable in both types.  The common UB is to print the value as if it was converted to `unsigned` before being passed.  When `UINT_MAX == 4294967295` (4-bytes) that prints the value as `-1 + (UINT_MAX + 1)` or "4294967295"`.

---

So with ID and UB, you get a result, but robust code would be re-written to depend on neither.